# how to get response from a function and validate another function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i click a button i want to validate two functions one by one and my functions are
validateEmail(email);
validatemobile(mobile);
what i am trying so far and my code is
when i click getotp button

```
$('.getotp').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var response;

var email=$('#email').val();
validateEmail(email);

if(response=true){  
var mobile=$('#mob').val();
validatemobile(mobile);}});
```

my emailvalidation function is

```
function validateEmail(email){

var emailReg = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
var valid = emailReg.test(email);


if(!valid) 
{


    $('.errornotice').text('Email Address Is Not Valid');


    response=false;



}
else
{
    response=true;
}
}//email validate function
```

and my mobile validation function is

```
function validatemobile(mobile){




//CHECK MOBILE NUMBER
 if(mobile=='')
{
    $('.errornotice').removeClass('nodisplay');
    $('.errornotice').text('Mobile Number can not be empty');
    e.preventDefault();
}
else if(mobile.toString().length>10 || mobile.toString().length<10 )
{
    $('.errornotice').removeClass('nodisplay');
    $('.errornotice').text('Mobile Number Must be 10 Digit');
    e.preventDefault();
}
//send OTP
else
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"otp.php",
        data:{mob:mobile},
        success: function(data){

            e.preventDefault();
            $('.errornotice').text('check your mobile and enter OTP');

            }//success


        })//ajax
}//else
}//mobile validate function
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: if both email and mobile field is empty and when i click getotp button it directly validate mobilenumber not email

Comment: directly shows Mobile Number can not be empty not email @sjm

Comment: It looks like Hanky has your answer the first validation will never be invalid